# can we implement google Admob Ads with Nokia Imaging sdk in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, admob

I'm developing an Application using Nokia Imaging sdk,Now i want to implement Admob Ads but i'm unable to see the adds. and if i implement that in any other demo application ads are displaying.Can anyone please suggest

```
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    public Add()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
           interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd("My Admob id ");
        AdRequest addRequest = new AdRequest();

        interstitialAd.ReceivedAd += OnAdReceived;
        interstitialAd.LoadAd(addRequest);
    }

    private void OnAdReceived(object sender, AdEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ad received successfully");
        interstitialAd.ShowAd();
    }
```

Comment: Hope these links helps https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/ https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/wp/banner

Comment: admob has nothing to do with nokia imaging sdk it will work for any    winows phone 8 and above app check with your permissions if are missing any.

Comment: Yuppp!!  i was Missing Permissions. Thanking Both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

admob has nothing to do with nokia imaging sdk it will work for any winows phone 8 and above app check with your permissions if are missing any